# VB6 Save String to File without the ---> "

Tags: vb6

I am trying to save this HTML to a HTML file. There are 2 problems with this code.

**1. It thinks that the "refresh" part is not part of the string**

I have tried a fix for this buy using Chr(34) instead of " but it still bring me onto error 2

**2. When I open the HTML File it has quotes around all the text and it looks rubbish**

How would I go about fixing these errors? Thanks.

```
  Dim nFileNum as Integer

    nFileNum = 4

    Open "WebWindow.html" For Output As #nFileNum 'Open the file to put information into

        Write #nFileNum, "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />" 'Refresh Script
        Write #nFileNum, "<P>10% Through the current test:</p>"
        Write #nFileNum, "<p>Invoices 1/20 (processing)</p>"
        Write #nFileNum, "<p>POs 0/20 (waiting)</p>"

    Close #nFileNum 'Close the File
```

---

**EDIT:**

Using double quotes kind of works but the output in the web window now looks like this:

```
"" "
10% Through the current test:

" "
Invoices 1/20 (processing)

" "
POs 0/20 (waiting)

"
```

and in the HTML file it looks like this:

```
"<meta http-equiv=""refresh"" content=""1"" />"
"<P>10% Through the current test:</p>"
"<p>Invoices 1/20 (processing)</p>"
"<p>POs 0/20 (waiting)</p>"
```

So I still have to deal with problem 2....

---

**EDIT EDIT! FIXED **

I fixed problem 1 with the double quotes (Thanks to you guys) and fixed problem 2 myself. Instead of using Write I used Print. Print does the same thing as write but does not put the quotes in the file with the string.

**My new working code:**

```
Function WebOutput()

Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim Line2 As String

Line2 = "<P>10% Through the current test:</p>"

nFileNum = 4

Open "C:\TestPartner\Config\WebWindow.html" For Output As #nFileNum 'Open the file to put information into

    Print #nFileNum, "<meta http-equiv=""refresh"" content=""1"" />" 'Refresh Script
    Print #nFileNum, Line2
    Print #nFileNum, "<p>Invoices 1/20 (processing)</p>"
    Print #nFileNum, "<p>POs 0/20 (waiting)</p>"

Close #nFileNum 'Close the File
```

Comment: Change the line to: `Write #nFileNum, "<meta http-equiv=""refresh"" content=""1"" />" 'Refresh Script`  (You need to double-up the quotes to escape them, in vb6)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but those Open/Write/Close methods were considered clunky even back when VB 6 was being used. You might want to consider switching to using the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: See edit on my original post.. :) Also I like use the Open/Write/Close method and have used it throughout my project so I would rather not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape quotes in VB you do `""` so try `"<meta http-equiv=""refresh"" content=""1"" />"`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function to replace any quote marks with double quotes in the string before you write it.

```
string = replace(string, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34))
```

Something like that. The should work. Play around with how many Chr(34) & chr(34) & chr(34) if two doesn't work.

You will have to modify your existing code, you can't get around it, but this is the easiest way to do it.